audio to video with ffmpeg
I would like to know if it is possible to combine video with audio using ffmpeg batch converter but the video should end when the audio sound ends. Does anyone know how to do this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Use the -shortest flag to end the stream when the audio stops.  The other way around requires padding the audio at the end to match the video length.

FFmpeg offers different commands that you can use to split up a video.
What you looking for is the -t option to specify a time limit.

How to set a video's duration in FFMPEG?

ffmpeg add audio but keep video length the same (not -shortest)

ffmpeg cut audio to video length if its longer in video file

How to trim a video using FFmpeg

Automatically changing audio files length to fit video 


